# Folder permissions when zip and unzip on Windows

Tags: windows, security, compression, backup, file-permissions

I've a webserver Windows 2003. When I do a backup in a zip of some folders, the permissions of the folder doesnt restore when i unzip the compress file. How can I do a zip saving the original permissions or how can i do a backup with all permissions keep intact?

I cant install any software, its a production server.

Comment: WinRAR might help as it also handles alternate data streams.

Comment: Use software made for backups rather than relying on zip.

Comment: I havent got winrar and i cant install any software, its a production server and another company has to do the deployment.

Comment: I know this is not the point of the question (and most of us have some unsupported legacy systems) but 2003 is EOL since `7/14/2015` and it would be wise to migrate it to something under support (or at least something which still gets security updates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used robocopy, its a cmd application that i can run and comes with Windows.

It works as:

```
robocopy {source} {destination} /COPY:DAT
```

Comment: Robocopy does not come with Server 2003, it is part of the resource pack back then, I believe 2003R2 did include it.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a two-step process. If that 2003 server has SP2 on it, you have access to the `icacls` utility. With that you can run:

```
icacls f:\inetpub\wwwhome\* /save f:\backups\rights-acls.txt /t /c
[zip f:\inetpub\wwwhome\
```

That will create a file with all of the rights stored in it, keep it with the zip. To restore

```
[unzip the file to the target]
icacls f:\inetpub\wwwhome /restore f:\backups\rights-acls.txt
```

If you don't have icacls on the system, there isn't much help. Happily, icacls is included on Windows Vista and higher, so if you can access the data via a mapped drive, you can run it from the client-side and drop the file where you need it.